# Como filtar un query_set por valores unicos Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Estoy tratando de obtener resultados de valores unicos  de un query_set en django. Lo que quiero es que me regrese cuantas clasificaciones unicas 
hay.

Ejemplo. En un Tabla tengo diferentes articulos que se clasifican por tipo

```
ID     |    NOMBRE    |    CLASIFICACION
1           Escoba         Limpieza
2           Trapeador      Limpieza
3           Tornillo       Herramienta
```

quiero que me regrese 2 clasificaciones  Limpieza y Herramienta. actualmente me regresa las 3 clasificaciones Limpieza, Limpieza y herramienta.

mi vista:

```
class ItemListView(ListView):
    model= Items

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(ItemListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['clasificacion'] = Items.objects.order_by('nombre').distinct('clasificacion')
        return context
```

Mi Models

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Items(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    codigo_proveedor = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    clasificacion = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    c_minima = models.IntegerField()
    c_actual = models.IntegerField()
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey('Proveedores', 
                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.nombre + '   -----   ' + 
                   self.clasificacion + '   -----    ' + 
                   str(self.c_actual)


class Proveedores(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    direccion1 = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    direccion2 = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    active =  models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

agradeceria su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa values

```
 contexto['clasificacion'] =  Items.objects.values('clasificacion').order_by('clasificacion').distinct()
```

La función 'distinct()' no acepta valores, así que antes hay que el 'values()' con los parámetros que queremos agrupar. Una vez se obtienen los valores deseados hay que ordenarlos por que los va agrupando según recorre la lista de valores

Te recomiendo que para casos como estos, donde un campo siempre tendrá los mismos 4 o 5 valores, uses choices en el modelo, te facilitará el desarrollo

Comment: Lo ehh intentado con .values() o .values_list() y me sigue tirando 3 valores

Comment: perdona se me olvido el order_by, esto esta comprobado si no te funciona asegurate que los registros que tienes en la tabla no sobre algún espacio. He modificado mi respuesta

Comment: ahora tengo un error  
` 'dict' object has no attribute 'clasificacion'`

Comment: tengo exactamente ese codigo en un proyecto y me funciona sin problema. prueba dos cosas añade luego de objects.all()   y pon order_by antes de value

Comment: Lo mismo . el error se presenta.

Comment: muestrame esa linea de codigo

Comment: context['clasificacion'] = Items.objects.all().order_by('clasificacion').values('clasificacion').distinct()

Comment: mi hermano ! que tonto mesiento me estaba dando el error por un for que puse para imprimir en consola el contenido de mi query_set ya me funciono !!!

Comment: no te preocupes a todos nos pasa a veces.  No olvides poner tu pregunta como respondida . Un saludo.

Comment: palomita verde verdad

Comment: si, cualquier cosa estoy para ayudar un saludo

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ! saludos